# Not able to apply for BigQuery API quota. Broken link?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to request BQ API quota. 
According to AIM I have - / 0 limit.
[image: AIM screenshot] 
When I click "apply for higher quota" I am being redirected to.. 
[Get Help Developing with Google BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/support?hl=en_US&_ga=2.253671625.-1196042777.1516466563) page that has nothing in common with BQ API. 
[image: How do people get anything done with GCP?]

That looks like a... Broken link?
Any ideas what is going on?

Thanks.

Comment: how did you get to that first screenshot?

Comment: Opened IAM & admin, then Quotas, then selected a checkbox next to  BigQuery API and clicked "Edit Quotas"

Comment: [File a bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0)?

Comment: Done.
b/72406749

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This quota metric is actually an internal-only quota bucket that shouldn't affect your usage of BQ. You can safely ignore it (and we'll hide it in the future).

BigQuery's quota limits are documented here:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas

If you'd like to request an increase in one of those quotas, please contact support:
https://cloud.google.com/support/

But note that not all quotas can be adjusted.